# $_POST - Form to email

Tags: php, html, forms, post

So i have used this website for a long time, and never had to ask before, but I am pulling my hair out! Help me please.

I am using a **simple** script i found using a form to send results to an email address. To start with the validation of 2 fields being full wont let it send, although the fields hold data - So i remove that condition and it will send an email, but it wont show the actual data displayed. Can you please look and suggest?

My PHP:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
        echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
    }
    $name - $_POST['name'];
    $description - $_POST['description'];
    $car_year - $_POST['car_year'];
    $big_brakes - $_POST['big_brakes'];
    $road_car - $_POST['road_car'];
    $type - $_POST['type'];
    $email - $_POST['email'];

    //Validate first
    if(empty($name)||empty($email)) 
    {
        echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
        exit;
    }

    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        echo "Bad email value!";
        exit;
    }

$email_from = 'marketing@part-box.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $name".

$to = "marketing@part-box.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>RAYS Wheels Quote</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>RAYS Wheels Quote</a></h1>
      <ul >
          <center><img src="images/Rays---Coming-soon-page_03.jpg" width="251" height="72" alt=""></td></center>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
              <div class="form_description">

            <center><p>Free Quote for RAYS Wheels, Give us the information we have asked for and we will find the Wheels for your Car.</p></center>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
              <li id="li_2" >
        <label for="description" >Car Make and Model</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label for="car_year">Car Year</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label for="big_brakes" >Big Brakes Fitted? Yes / No</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label for="road_car">Road Car / Motor sport?</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label for="type" >Type of RAYS Wheel</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
        <label class="email" >Your Email Address</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
        <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="793428" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>


            </ul>
        </form> 
        <script language="JavaScript">
// Code for validating the form
// Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
// for details
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myemailform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
        <div id="footer"></a>
        <center><center><img src="images/Rays---Form-Footer.jpg" width="624" height="264" alt="Makes"></td></div>
    </div></center>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, change all `- $_POST` to `= $_POST` And if you got this from a tutorial somewhere, report it to ICANN (groan)

Comment: Plus, your named attributes don't match.

Comment: the only one that doesnt match is Car model and make - I thought the Description tag is the only thing that would make a differnce? aslong as that is referenced?

Comment: also changing - $_POST tp =$_POST does nothing, and it was a tutorial.

Comment: You have `$_POST['email'];` but your form's Email element is called `name="element_6"` so that won't work. You either have to change it to `name="email"` or change `$_POST['email'];` to `$_POST['element_6'];` and match the others as well.

Comment: There is far too much work for me to put in an actual answer. You need to match your `$_POST['variables']` to your `name="variables"` in your HTML form.

Comment: right, so i had the wrong fields reference, thank you i will try this and let you know.

Comment: Plus, I believe `Wind Shear` made the actual changes for you in an Edit. So give that a try first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

Change this from this:

```
$name - $_POST['name'];
$description - $_POST['description'];
$car_year - $_POST['car_year'];
$big_brakes - $_POST['big_brakes'];
$road_car - $_POST['road_car'];
$type - $_POST['type'];
$email - $_POST['email'];
```

to this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$car_year = $_POST['car_year'];
$big_brakes = $_POST['big_brakes'];
$road_car = $_POST['road_car'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

**HTML**

Change from this:

```
<label for="name">name</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
              <li id="li_2" >
        <label for="description" >Car Make and Model</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label for="car_year">Car Year</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label for="big_brakes" >Big Brakes Fitted? Yes / No</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label for="road_car">Road Car / Motor sport?</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label for="type" >Type of RAYS Wheel</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
        <label class="email" >Your Email Address</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div>
```

To This:

```
<label for="name">name</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_1" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>
      <li id="li_2" >
<label for="description" >Car Make and Model</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_2" name="description" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_6" >
<label for="car_year">Car Year</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_6" name="car_year" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_3" >
<label for="big_brakes" >Big Brakes Fitted? Yes / No</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_3" name="big_brakes" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_4" >
<label for="road_car">Road Car / Motor sport?</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_4" name="road_car" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>       <li id="li_5" >
<label for="type" >Type of RAYS Wheel</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_5" name="type" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div> 
</li>
<label class="email" >Your Email Address</label>
<div>
    <input id="element_5" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
```

**Explanation**

In PHP, change the minus sign to equal sign when setting the value from the `$_POST` variable.

In HTML, the value of the input will be passed to PHP script will be based on the `name` attribute. So, in order to pass the value after the submission, the HTML code like below:

```
`<input id="someid" name="test" />`
```

will be passed to PHP as

```
$_POST['test']
```

Comment: Thanks i had tried this, and just did again - it does not give me the solution.

Comment: He tried this, so that's why he put in `-` instead of `=` (good one) like it's going to work. Classic "can of worms" question. There's a lot more things going wrong with OP's code than this. Do double-check.

Comment: @user3311113, I added the explanation.

Comment: I said that, and then it starts showing the last 2 fields as the actual id. so $type and $email come through